# CSS selector for first child, if it happens to be of type

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have some HTML like so:

```
<li>
  Very
  <span class="node-variable">high</span>
  temperature
</li>
```

and

```
<li>
  <span class="node-variable">high</span>
  temperature
</li>
```

In the 2nd version I would like to capitalize the `high` so it reads as `High`. I do not want to capitalize the first instance.

So I'd like:

`Very high temperature`
and
`High temperature`

My idea was to apply some CSS to select .node-variable, where it's the first child, but not if it isn't. Is this possible?

Comment: You are missing the quotes for the `node-variable`

Comment: Confused with the question. So you want only apply css style to a specific span?

Comment: To a specific span, only if it's the first node (text included) in an element. I know CSS does not have selectors for raw text, so perhaps it's not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in pure CSS.

Using the CSS first-letter pseudo element seems to pick up the first letter even if that is in your span element:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    li::first-letter {
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li>
      Very
      <span class="node-variable">high</span> temperature
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="node-variable">high</span> temperature
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wtf? So simple haha. How did I not try this!? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS Pseudo-elements `:first-letter`:

```css
li::first-letter{
 text-transform: capitalize;
 }
```

```html
<li>
  <span>Very</span>
  <span class="node-variable">high</span>
  temperature
</li>
<li>
  <span class="node-variable">high</span>
  temperature
</li>
```

Comment: Damn. I don't think I am able to change the markup

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra, you could do that by using JS, but seems too complex. Just curious why you do that. Why don't you just apply `text-transform: capitalize` to `li`?

Comment: Adding capitalize to the li won't work. It will capitalize the first letter of every element in the li. If I have multi node-variable spans, it will capitalize each

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra, i see you only want to make the every first character in the `li` become uppercase. If you assign it to the `li`, it should work and won't capitlize multi node variables.

Comment: I just tried. It capitalizes the node-variable spans. Are you sure? Perhaps I have something else going on

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra, I know this edit is a little bit late since you have accept an answer, but you could also use `:first-letter` to select the first word and use `text-transform: capitalize` which is your previous trying.